# Best way of reducing number of parquet files

Tags: pyspark, parquet, amazon-emr, aws-glue, amazon-athena

i have around one million of very small parquet files(~ 14 KB) and i would like to merge them into files of a size suited for HDFS (128 MB). I want to do this on AWS.

My Ideas were:

1. spark.read and then coalesce and then write via EMR
2. the same as 1 vie glue
3. CTAS statement via athena

Do you have other ideas? Which one is best practice or the least expensive (Note: there are no time limits)?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Athena is an excellent way to combine multiple same-format files into fewer, larger files.

The basic steps would be:

- **Create a table in Amazon Athena** that points to your existing data in Amazon S3 (it includes all objects in subdirectories of that Location, too). An easy way to create this table definition is to use an **AWS Glue crawler** -- just point it to your data and it will create the table.
- Use a `CREATE TABLE AS` command to copy the data to a new location:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table
WITH (
 format = 'PARQUET',
 parquet_compression = 'SNAPPY',
 external_location = 's3://bucket/folder/',
 partitioned_by = ARRAY['optional'],
 bucketed_by = ARRAY[ bucket_name[,…] ]
)
AS SELECT * 
FROM old_table;
```

The use of a **partition is optional**, but can greatly improve performance if there is a particular field commonly used with a `WHERE` clause.

You can control the number of files by using **bucketing**, but it is often better to just let Athena choose the bucket quantities and sizes.

See: [Bucketing vs Partitioning - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/bucketing-vs-partitioning.html)

Comment: is this also cost efficient and usable with the high number of files ( 1 Million)?

Comment: Amazon Athena is charged at $5/TB of data read from disk. (That's why compressed data is better!) If it fails to read that quantity of files, you might need to do it by Prefix to do a portion of the files at a time.

Comment: i am gonna try this, thank you for now

Comment: @realslimjp How did it work for you? I am still not sure how did creating a table merge small parquet files together?

Comment: Yeah it works like a charm. We are refucing 2 Million of small files to 28 bigger parquet files in like 5 minutes. But we found out using „Unload“ statement is even less complicated and more straightforward for our usecase. The only thing you have to keep in mind is, if you have more than 2 million (idk the exact number) you could get an RateRequest slowdown from S3 which terminates your query. we‘ve seen that a couple times